# Validate datetime input using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to validate a datetime user input using javascript for my school project, scheduling system.

I have already done this server side,
is this possible client side?

```
<!--My code looks like this-->
<body>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="dateTimeInput">
    <input type="button" onclick="checkDateTimeInput()" value="Submit">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkDateTimeInput(){
    var dateTime = document.getElementById('dateTimeInput');
    if(dateTime /* not 2 or more days ahead */)
        alert("Must be 2 days ahead");
    }else if(dateTime /* is sunday */){
        alert("It is Sunday");
    }else if(dateTime /* not between 8AM-5PM */){
        alert("Time must be between 8AM-5PM");
    }else{
        alert("Success")
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I suggest to use library like moment.js or date-fns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
<body>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="dateTimeInput">
    <input type="button" onclick="checkDateTimeInput()" value="Submit">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with- 
     locales.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let date = document.getElementById('dateTimeInput')
        let dateToValidate = null

        date.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
            dateToValidate = e.target.value
        })

        function checkDateTimeInput() {
            const today = moment().add(2, 'day')
            if (dateToValidate) {
                dateToValidate = moment(dateToValidate)
                if (dateToValidate.format('dd') === 'Su') {
                    alert('Sunday is not allowed')
                }
                else if (today >= dateToValidate) {
                    alert('Date has to be more than two days in the future')
                }
                else {
                    alert(dateToValidate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
                }

            } else {
                alert('Enter a valid date')
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but my browser console returns this: 
GET https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-%20%20%20%20%20%20locales.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: sorry something went wrong when I edited the answer: Replace the address after src= with https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js

Answer (score 2):

You can use a JavaScript `Date` object to hold the value of your input and manipulate date information, and you can learn much more about these [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Here's a detailed explanation of how to use them to check for just the date difference (intentionally verbose for teaching purposes):

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", checkDatetimeInput);

function checkDatetimeInput(){

  // Stores values in local variables
  const
    datetimeInput = document.getElementById("datetimeInput"), // HTML element
    datetimeInputValue = datetimeInput.value, // Value property in the HTML element
    dateObject = new Date(datetimeInputValue), // JS `Date` object
    dateObjectTimestamp = dateObject.getTime(), // Timestamp (milliseconds)
    dateString = dateObject.toUTCString(); // Human-readable string (See also `toLocaleString`)        

  // Prints contents of variables
  console.log(`datetimeInputValue: ${ datetimeInputValue }`);
  console.log(`dateObjectTimestamp: ${ dateObjectTimestamp }`);
  console.log(`dateString: ${ dateString }`);
  console.log(``);

  // Calls function to check date difference, stores result in `tooSoon`
  const
    tooSoon = isLessThanTwoDaysFromNow(dateObject),

  // Calls remaining validation functions, stores results in variables
    sunday = isSunday(dateObject),
    daytimeHours = isBetweenEightAndFive(dateObject);

  // Prints final output
  let output = "";
  if     (tooSoon)      { output = "That's too soon"; }
  else if(sunday)       { output = "That's a Sunday"; }
  else if(!daytimeHours){ output = "That's not between 8 and 5"; }
  else                  { output = "Success! -- but did you check Sunday & time of day?"; }
  console.log(output);
}

function isLessThanTwoDaysFromNow(dateObjectFromInput){

  // Stores values in local variables
  const
    nowObject = new Date(), // Default Date constructor uses the current time
    nowObjectTimestamp = nowObject.getTime(), // `getTime` gives a timestamp in milliseconds        
    datetimeObjectTimestamp = dateObjectFromInput.getTime(),
    differenceInMilliseconds = datetimeObjectTimestamp - nowObjectTimestamp,
    differenceInDays = differenceInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
    diffferenceInDaysRoundedDown = Math.floor(differenceInDays),
    differenceInDaysIsLessThanTwo = differenceInDays < 2;

  // Prints contents of variables
  console.log(`differenceInMilliseconds: ${ differenceInMilliseconds }`);
  console.log(`differenceInDays: ${ differenceInDays }`);
  console.log(`diffferenceInDaysRoundedDown: ${ diffferenceInDaysRoundedDown }`)
  console.log(`differenceInDaysIsLessThanTwo: ${ differenceInDaysIsLessThanTwo }`);

  // Returns `true` or `false` to code that called this function
  return differenceInDaysIsLessThanTwo;
}

function isBetweenEightAndFive(dateObjectFromInput){
  
  let result = true;

  // Test time of day here
  // (Be aware of the difference between UTC time and local time)

  return result;
}

function isSunday(dateObjectFromInput){
  
  let result = false;

  // Test day of week here
  // (Be aware of the difference between UTC time and local time.
  //  For example, Sunday 11:00PM EST might be Monday 4:00AM UTC.)

  return result;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="datetimeInput" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" />
```

I leave it to you to check the day of the week and the time of day.

You can find useful methods for this at the link above (such as the `.getDay` method, which gives you a number from zero to six according to the local timezone.)

(Note: If you need to find out what timezone the script is running in (in minutes, relative to UTC time), use `.getTimezoneOffset`.)

Comment: thanks for teaching me, i just added few more lines of code to make it work.

Comment: i posted my own answer, it is less object oriented but works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
 btn.addEventListener("click", checkDatetimeInput);

 function checkDatetimeInput(){
 var errors = "";
    // Stores values in local variables
    const
  datetimeInput = document.getElementById("datetimeInput"), // HTML element
  datetimeInputValue = datetimeInput.value, // Value property in the HTML element
  dateObject = new Date(datetimeInputValue), // JS `Date` object
  dateObjectTimestamp = dateObject.getTime(), // Timestamp (milliseconds)
  dateString = dateObject.toUTCString(); // Human-readable string (See also `toLocaleString`)        

    // Prints contents of variables
    console.log(`datetimeInputValue: ${ datetimeInputValue }`);
     console.log(`dateObjectTimestamp: ${ dateObjectTimestamp }`);
     console.log(`dateString: ${ dateString }`);

    // Calls function to check date difference, stores result in `notSoon`
     const notSoon = isAtLeastTwoDaysFromNow(dateObject)
     if(!notSoon)
      errors += "Must be 2 or more days ahead";
    // Now you will need to do the other two checks (day of week and time of day)...

    var day = dateObject.getDay();
    if(day == 0)
     errors += "\nSunday not allowed";

    var hourTime = dateObject.getHours();
    if(hourTime < 8 || hourTime > 17)
     errors += "\nInvalid time";
    alert(errors);
 }

 function isAtLeastTwoDaysFromNow(myDatetime){

     // Stores values in local variables
     const
  nowObject = new Date(), // Default Date constructor uses the current time
  nowObjectTimestamp = nowObject.getTime(), // `getTime` gives a timestamp in milliseconds        
  datetimeObjectTimestamp = myDatetime.getTime(),
  differenceInMilliseconds = datetimeObjectTimestamp - nowObjectTimestamp,
  differenceInDays = differenceInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
  diffferenceInDaysRoundedDown = Math.floor(differenceInDays);
  differenceInDaysIsTwoOrMore = differenceInDays >= 2;

     // Prints contents of variables
     console.log(`differenceInMilliseconds: ${ differenceInMilliseconds }`);
     console.log(`differenceInDays: ${ differenceInDays }`);
     console.log(`diffferenceInDaysRoundedDown: ${ diffferenceInDaysRoundedDown }`)
     console.log(`differenceInDaysIsTwoOrMore: ${ differenceInDaysIsTwoOrMore }`);

     // Returns `true` or `false` to code that called this function
     return differenceInDaysIsTwoOrMore;
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="datetimeInput" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" />
```

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", checkDatetimeInput);

function checkDatetimeInput(){

  // Stores values in local variables
  const
    datetimeInput = document.getElementById("datetimeInput"), // HTML element
    datetimeInputValue = datetimeInput.value, // Value property in the HTML element
    dateObject = new Date(datetimeInputValue), // JS `Date` object
    dateObjectTimestamp = dateObject.getTime(), // Timestamp (milliseconds)
    dateString = dateObject.toUTCString(); // Human-readable string (See also `toLocaleString`)        

  // Prints contents of variables
  console.log(`datetimeInputValue: ${ datetimeInputValue }`);
  console.log(`dateObjectTimestamp: ${ dateObjectTimestamp }`);
  console.log(`dateString: ${ dateString }`);

  // Calls function to check date difference, stores result in `tooSoon`
  const
    tooSoon = isLessThanTwoDaysFromNow(dateObject),

  // Calls remaining validation function, stores results in variables
    sunday = isSunday(dateObject),
    daytimeHours = isBetweenEightAndFive(dateObject);

  // Prints final output
  let output = "";
  if     (tooSoon)      { output = "That's too soon"; }
  else if(sunday)       { output = "That's a Sunday"; }
  else if(!daytimeHours){ output = "That's not between 8 and 5"; }
  else                  { output = "Success! -- but did you check Sunday & time of day?"; }
  console.log(output);
}

function isLessThanTwoDaysFromNow(dateObjectFromInput){

  // Stores values in local variables
  const
    nowObject = new Date(), // Default Date constructor uses the current time
    nowObjectTimestamp = nowObject.getTime(), // `getTime` gives a timestamp in milliseconds        
    datetimeObjectTimestamp = dateObjectFromInput.getTime(),
    differenceInMilliseconds = datetimeObjectTimestamp - nowObjectTimestamp,
    differenceInDays = differenceInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
    diffferenceInDaysRoundedDown = Math.floor(differenceInDays),
    differenceInDaysIsLessThanTwo = differenceInDays < 2;

  // Prints contents of variables
  console.log(`differenceInMilliseconds: ${ differenceInMilliseconds }`);
  console.log(`differenceInDays: ${ differenceInDays }`);
  console.log(`diffferenceInDaysRoundedDown: ${ diffferenceInDaysRoundedDown }`)
  console.log(`differenceInDaysIsLessThanTwo: ${ differenceInDaysIsLessThanTwo }`);

  // Returns `true` or `false` to code that called this function
  return differenceInDaysIsLessThanTwo;
}

function isBetweenEightAndFive(dateObjectFromInput){
  
  let result = true;

  // Test time of day here
  // (Be aware of the difference between UTC time and local time)

  return result; // 
}

function isSunday(dateObjectFromInput){
  
  let result = false;

  // Test day of week here
  // (Be aware of the difference between UTC time and local time.
  //  For example, Sunday 11:00PM EST might be Monday 4:00AM UTC.)

  return result;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="datetimeInput" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" />
```

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", checkDatetimeInput);

function checkDatetimeInput(){

  // Stores values in local variables
  const
    datetimeInput = document.getElementById("datetimeInput"), // HTML element
    datetimeInputValue = datetimeInput.value, // Value property in the HTML element
    dateObject = new Date(datetimeInputValue), // JS `Date` object
    dateObjectTimestamp = dateObject.getTime(), // Timestamp (milliseconds)
    dateString = dateObject.toUTCString(); // Human-readable string (See also `toLocaleString`)        

  // Prints contents of variables
  console.log(`datetimeInputValue: ${ datetimeInputValue }`);
  console.log(`dateObjectTimestamp: ${ dateObjectTimestamp }`);
  console.log(`dateString: ${ dateString }`);

  // Calls function to check date difference, stores result in `tooSoon`
  const
    tooSoon = isLessThanTwoDaysFromNow(dateObject),

  // Calls remaining validation function, stores results in variables
    sunday = isSunday(dateObject),
    daytimeHours = isBetweenEightAndFive(dateObject);

  // Prints final output
  let output = "";
  if     (tooSoon)      { output = "That's too soon"; }
  else if(sunday)       { output = "That's a Sunday"; }
  else if(!daytimeHours){ output = "That's not between 8 and 5"; }
  else                  { output = "Success! -- but did you check Sunday & time of day?"; }
  console.log(output);
}

function isLessThanTwoDaysFromNow(dateObjectFromInput){

  // Stores values in local variables
  const
    nowObject = new Date(), // Default Date constructor uses the current time
    nowObjectTimestamp = nowObject.getTime(), // `getTime` gives a timestamp in milliseconds        
    datetimeObjectTimestamp = dateObjectFromInput.getTime(),
    differenceInMilliseconds = datetimeObjectTimestamp - nowObjectTimestamp,
    differenceInDays = differenceInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
    diffferenceInDaysRoundedDown = Math.floor(differenceInDays),
    differenceInDaysIsLessThanTwo = differenceInDays < 2;

  // Prints contents of variables
  console.log(`differenceInMilliseconds: ${ differenceInMilliseconds }`);
  console.log(`differenceInDays: ${ differenceInDays }`);
  console.log(`diffferenceInDaysRoundedDown: ${ diffferenceInDaysRoundedDown }`)
  console.log(`differenceInDaysIsLessThanTwo: ${ differenceInDaysIsLessThanTwo }`);

  // Returns `true` or `false` to code that called this function
  return differenceInDaysIsLessThanTwo;
}

function isBetweenEightAndFive(dateObjectFromInput){
  
  let result = true;

  // Test time of day here
  // (Be aware of the difference between UTC time and local time)

  return result; // 
}

function isSunday(dateObjectFromInput){
  
  let result = false;

  // Test day of week here
  // (Be aware of the difference between UTC time and local time.
  //  For example, Sunday 11:00PM EST might be Monday 4:00AM UTC.)

  return result;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="datetimeInput" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" />
```